# Zip file in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using this code to backup my mysql database, and it works fine for my purposes.This script save my backup as .sql file how can I zip that sql file.Here's the code

```
$username = "***";
$password = "***";
$hostname = "***";
$database = "***";
$username =escapeshellcmd($username);
$password =escapeshellcmd($password);
$hostname =escapeshellcmd($hostname);
$database =escapeshellcmd($database);
$backupFile=''.date("Y-m-d-H-i-s").$database.'.sql';
$command = "mysqldump -u$username -p$password -h$hostname $database > $backupFile";
system($command, $result);
echo $result;
```

Comment: I'm sure this can be Googled rather easily. I would start by entering `zip file in php`.

Comment: Normally you can pipe the data into the zip command directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a pure PHP solution, I believe this should do it: (from http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php

```
$z = new ZipArchive();
$z->open("sqldump.zip", ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
$z->addFile($backupFile);
$z->close();
```

Comment: Thanks man !! This is  exactly what I need.I'll accept this answer when pending time runs out

Answer (score 4):

Just pipe the output to gzip or similar

```
mysqldump -uroot | gzip > backupfile.zip
```

http://mediakey.dk/~cc/compressing-mysqldump-output-mysql-gzip-bzip2-and-lzma-7z/

Answer (score 0):

You could use `tar`: `tar -cf archive.tar yourfile.sql` using `exec()`

Comment: `tar` on its own is not a compression, but an archive format. Right now you are wrapping a single file in an archive without compression, or any other benefit ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
`$backupFile=''.date("Y-m-d-H-i-s").$database.'.sql';`
```

to

```
`$backupFile=''.date("Y-m-d-H-i-s").$database.'.zip';`
```

or to any other zip file type. It is a shell command and can save in many different compressed formats.